# javascript regex split by semicolon except &amp;

Tags: javascript, regex

I need `&amp;` to remain in the string.

Example:

```
"Rajagiri School of Engineering &amp; Technology;Indian School of Mines University;"
```

Output should be:

```
['Rajagiri School of Engineering &amp; Technology', 'Indian School of Mines University']
```

Comment: Add the code you've attempted.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/bG6eE1/1 will work but have limitations like there cannot be multiple `;` within a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `replace` with a callback and discard the result of there is `&amp` before `;`.

```
var str = "Rajagiri School of Engineering &amp; Technology;Indian School of Mines University;";

var arr = str.replace(/(&amp)?;/g, function($0, $1) { return $1=="&amp"? $1+";" : "\n";
          }).split("\n").filter(Boolean);
```

**Output:**

```
["Rajagiri School of Engineering &amp; Technology",
 "Indian School of Mines University"]
```

Comment: Why not regular expression?

Comment: Because JS regex doesn't support lookbehind

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match everything outside of "real `;`s":

```
(?:&amp;|[^;])+
```

would work. Or `(?:&\w+;|[^;])+` if more than just `&amp;` entities are to be expected.

If your regex engine supports split operations, perhaps this regex (matching semicolons only if not preceded by `&amp`) is also a good idea

```
(?<!&amp);
```

To also allow other entities like above, `(?<!&\w+);` can be used if your regex implementation supports indefinite repetition inside [lookbehind assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Most don't, though, .NET being an exception.

In Javascript:

```
var data = "Rajagiri School of Engineering &amp; Technology;Indian School of Mines University;"
var regex = "(?<!&amp);";
var result = data.split(regex);
console.log(result);
```

```html
<p id="demo">Click the button to change the text in this paragraph.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var data = "Rajagiri School of Engineering &amp; Technology;Indian School of Mines University;"
    var regex = "(?<!&amp);";
    var result = data.split(regex);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: The output gives an array with this: `"Rajagiri School of Engineering &amp; Technology;Indian School of Mines University;"` in index[0]  Desired Output is: ["Rajagiri School of Engineering `&amp; Technology`", "Indian School of Mines University"]

Comment: Your result is incorrect. It gives the result `["Rajagiri School of Engineering &amp; Technology;Indian School of Mines University;"]`

Comment: @JimanSahariah Please read it carefully. I already wrote that if you want to match semicolon but &amp; then you should go with this `(?<!&amp);`. I edited the answer.

Comment: @ToanNguyen your answer doesn't give the desired output.

Comment: Lookbehinds are not supported by JS